# Create a method to select and display all data from a single table database

Tags: java

I need to create a method that selects all data from a single table database titled Accounts - as you see my effort below is only partially complete as I'm unsure how to proceed with the method (I'm new to Java), any suggestions re. what I need to do to make it a complete, standalone method please?

```
String select = "Select * from Accounts";


                results = statement.executeQuery(select);
                    }
                    catch(SQLException e){
                       System.out.println("Cannot execute query");
                       e.printStackTrace();
                       System.exit(1);
                          }

                    try{
                 while (results.next()){
                    System.out.println("Name:    " + results.getInt(1));
                    System.out.println("Address: " + results.getString(2) + " " + 
                    results.getString(3));
                         System.out.println("Salary:        " + results.getString(4));
                         System.out.println("Grade:        " + results.getString(5));
                         System.out.println("Year:        " + results.getInt(6));
                         System.out.println("Tax Rate:        " + results.getDouble(7));
                         System.out.println();
                     }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException e){
                         System.out.println("Error retrieving data");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                       System.exit(1);
                    }
```

Comment: What do you need here? Do you know how to connect to a database via JDBC etc? If not there are many tutorials online on how to do this for a number of different databases (oracle, mysql etc.)

Comment: Nothing jumps out as being wrong with this. Have you tried running it? Does it do what you expect? If yes, we're set. If not, what were you expecting and how is it different?

Comment: Yes, I have setup connectivity to the database and can write data to same but I'm just not sure how to write a method to select all the data from the database and print it to a JTable

Comment: yes, it looks ok and works when run within another method but i need to create a seperate method for it and don't know whether it should be something like 'public static select etc. etc.  the basics really but as i said, i'm very new to this stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking at ?

```
 public static Object[][] results() {
    int count = 0;
    String select = "Select * from Accounts";        
    results = statement.executeQuery(select);
    try {
        while (results.next()) {
            count++;
        }
        results = statement.executeQuery(select);


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot execute query");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Object data[][] = new Object[count][7];
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while (results.next()) {
            data[i][0] = results.getInt(1);
            data[i][1] = results.getString(2);
            data[i][2] = results.getString(3);
            data[i][3] = results.getString(4);
            data[i][4] = results.getString(5);
            data[i][5] = results.getString(6);
            data[i][6] = results.getString(7);
            i++;
            /*
            System.out.println("Name:    " + results.getInt(1));
            System.out.println("Address: " + results.getString(2) + " " + 
            results.getString(3));
            System.out.println("Salary:        " + results.getString(4));
            System.out.println("Grade:        " + results.getString(5));
            System.out.println("Year:        " + results.getInt(6));
            System.out.println("Tax Rate:        " + results.getDouble(7));
            System.out.println();
             */
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error retrieving data");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

I didn't test this but you can make use of this if this is what you are looking for..

--EDIT--
You can call this function and use the returned result to construct your JTable. I guess you know how to construct the JTable if not have a look at the [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)